# factorial method doesn't work well!

Tags: java, math, factorial

Hi
this is a factorial method but it prints 0 in the console please help me thanks

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo obj = new Demo();
        System.out.println(obj.factorial(500));
    }

    public int factorial(int n) {
        int fact = 1;

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            fact= fact*i;
        }
        return fact;
    }
```

EDITED:will return Infinity!

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo obj = new Demo();
        System.out.println(obj.factorial(500));
    }

    public double  factorial(long n) {
       double fact = 1;

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            fact= fact*i;
        }
        return fact;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use BigInteger man! Know your Language first. \m/

Comment: You should be using ln(gamma) function and memoization.  gamma(n+1) = n!.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since `500!` equals `1220136825991110068701238785423046926253574342803192842192413588385845373153881997605496447502203281863013616477148203584163378722078177200480785205159329285477907571939330603772960859086270429174547882424912726344305670173270769461062802310452644218878789465754777149863494367781037644274033827365397471386477878495438489595537537990423241061271326984327745715546309977202781014561081188373709531016356324432987029563896628911658974769572087926928871281780070265174507768410719624390394322536422605234945850129918571501248706961568141625359056693423813008856249246891564126775654481886506593847951775360894005745238940335798476363944905313062323749066445048824665075946735862074637925184200459369692981022263971952597190945217823331756934581508552332820762820023402626907898342451712006207714640979456116127629145951237229913340169552363850942885592018727433795173014586357570828355780158735432768888680120399882384702151467605445407663535984174430480128938313896881639487469658817504506926365338175055478128640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` you can't fit it into an `int` (which ranges up to `2147483647`).

- Using an `int` you can only store up to `12!`.
- Using a `long` you'll get up to `20!`
- Using a `double` you'll get up to `170!`.
- By convention 0! equals 1;

Here is a solution using `BigInteger`:

```
public static BigInteger factorial(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    BigInteger n = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
    while (--i > 0) {
        n = n.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: To improve performance, you could also check i first and switch to BigInteger if needed ^^!

Comment: That would be a minor improvement, as it only optimizes the method for really small input-values.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way you can fit `500!` on a 32-bit `int`.

For calculations involving large numbers, consider using a `double` or a [`BigInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), depending on whether you want an approximate or an exact answer.

(Actually, for `500!`, even a `double` would not be enough: `Double.MAX_VALUE` is 1.7976931348623157E+308, which will "only" let you go up to `170!`)

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you should be looking into if you need to calculate the factorial function:

1) [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). This will dramatically speed up your calculations, since the factorial function has a recursive definition. What you do is cache previous calculations, so when you ask for `k!`, you can get it in one step by calculating `k*((k-1)!)` if you have `(k-1)!` cached.

2) [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). If you need to calculate large factorials, you can approximate them very rapidly this way, and with guaranteed bounds on the error, so you can tell whether the approximation will be acceptably close for your application.

If you do neither of these, you will find that there is some relatively small `k` for which you simply can't calculate `k!` in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

[Grodriguez is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905658/factorial-method-doesnt-work-well/3905674#3905674) - this is almost certainly caused by integer overflow.

If you test your method with more modest inputs it appears to return the right output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Demo obj = new Demo();
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      System.out.println(i + "! = " + obj.factorial(i));
}
```

`500!` is **massive**; when testing your function, starting with smaller inputs would be prudent.

Answer (score 0):

`500!` is ***way*** too big to fit a long, or double.
You would have to use other techniques to get this.

But first, what kind of program needs `500!`?

Comment: _what kind of program needs 500!?_  Combinatorics problems frequently have insanely large numbers.

Comment: @Tony, my intention was to tell OP that his case of 500! was *probably* irrelevant for his case. Perhaps poorly worded.

Answer (score 0):

There are some very nice optimization for the implementation of factorizations: see for instance [luschny.de](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/download.html) for a nice implementation of them in Java. Some require more mathematical insight then others... Have fun with the library :-)