# How do I write my Main class with invoking my factorial method

Tags: java, factorial

This is my calculation method to find the factorial of the users number.

```
public class Factorial {

   public static double factorial(double x) {
   double fact = 1;

   for (int i=2 ; i <= x ; i++) {
     fact = fact * i;
   }

   return fact;
}
```

The main is what I think is my issue, i just cant figure out how to properly invoke my void method so it will work correctly

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number: ");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
    int fact = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The factorial of the number is: "+ fact);
}
```

Comment: Change `int fact = Integer.parseInt (inputStr);` to `int fact = factorial(x);`. Keep in mind that it's easy to overflow the primitive data types when computing a factorial: [factorial method doesn't work well!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905658/factorial-method-doesnt-work-well)

Comment: Where do you invoke your `factorial` method *at all*?

Comment: You basically never call the method.

Comment: ‘*my void method*’ What?!

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final double factorial = Factorial.factorial(2.3);
    }
}
```

You could do it like that.